# Android in-app-purchase how to get expiration date of subscription

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-inapp-purchase

I have subscription feature in my app. Is there any way can I get expiration date of subscribed product without any additional code on the server?

I have searched a lot and didn't get the answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, you must send a request to the Google API service specifing the product `SKU` and the `purchaseToken`